# JBehave + Arquillian

Tags: java, testing, bdd, jboss-arquillian, jbehave

Is anyone aware of an Arquillian runner for Jbehave? The only one I've found is [this one](https://github.com/VineetReynolds/arquillian-testrunner-jbehave) and it hasn't been maintained for two years. I was wondering if there actually exists something that is maintained and released.

Answer (score 3):

This guy's writeup of his work on the base stuff you cite in your question seems promising.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2099020/open-source-tools/integrating-arquillian-and-jbehave.html

I've used Vineet Renolds' stuff from github and it works, but if you use it as is, it binds you to an older and much less functional version of shrink-wrap, particularly around the resolvers.